Propagating the cordyline from cutting didn't work
I have a cordyline plant that was becoming leggy so I thought to cut the stems from the leggy stem and propagate it. I cut the healthy stem into 4 pieces, planted them into the soil, and then watered it. After that, I covered it with a polybag to create a humid environment. After 2-3 days, I removed the polybag and then put them to the bright light. Don't know what I did wrong I could not see any roots growing or any leaves for 1 month.
I have seen so many videos but they didn't give detailed information on propagating plant by covering. Can anyone please guide me on how to propagate stems using covering them with a polybag or something? Do we need to remove the cover or keep it till we see some growth in the stems? Also how to water it?

Here's the thing: you were on the right track with the polybag! It's all about creating a cozy, humid haven for those cuttings to focus on root production. But sometimes, we gotta be careful not to smother them with good intentions.
Watering woes:  Think of that polybag like a tiny greenhouse. It traps moisture, so watering needs to be gentle. We don't want the soil soggy; it should just be nicely damp. Stick your finger in there –  if the top inch feels dry, then give it a drink. Drainage holes are your best friend here, so make sure your pot has some to prevent a watery graveyard.
Lighten Up:  Bright light is great, but harsh afternoon sun can be a bit much for these newbies. Think dappled sunlight filtering through leaves, or a nice spot by a bright window that doesn't get direct sun.
Rooting Rocket Fuel (Optional):  Have you heard of rooting hormone? It's like a magic potion for encouraging those roots to sprout. Not essential, but it can definitely give your cuttings a boost. Just dip the cut ends in a little rooting hormone before planting, and watch those roots go!
Patience is a Gardener's Virtue:  Growing roots takes time, my friend. Don't get discouraged if you don't see anything happening right away. Give your cuttings 4-6 weeks to work their magic underground. Trust the process!
Now, the Polybag Party Trick:  The bag is great for keeping things humid, but we don't want a stagnant party. Here's the trick:
Poke a few tiny holes in the top of the bag for some air circulation. Think of it as ventilation for your mini greenhouse.
Every few days, give the inside of the bag a gentle mist to keep things moist, but don't overdo it. You don't want condensation dripping on the leaves.
Signs of Success:  Once you see those tiny green leaves peeking out, you know your cuttings are happy campers with sprouted roots! That's your cue to gradually introduce more air by opening the bag for longer periods. Eventually, you can take the party off completely.
With a little TLC and these tips, your cordyline cuttings will thrive in no time. Remember, patience and the right balance of moisture and light are essential. Happy propagating!

thank you for this great suggestion. I will try this way.

Sure, let me know how it went.

Sure. I will give you update once I try this way again.
